# Is there a way to make a app that gives your computer more memory and or speeds up it up in C#

Tags: c#, performance, memory

Is it possible to make a app that makes your computer run faster and or increase the memory of your computer? for example like window's readyboost or something like that in C#? my computer is running low on memory space but I don't want to delete any games, It would be cool to be able to make a app that provides memory to my computer like a USB or something and also speed it up.

Comment: you mean disk capacity instead of memory? and anyway, why make a program like this yourself when there's already so much out there in this pretty specialized field of business??

Comment: Not really a programming question...

Comment: "my computer is running low on memory space but I don't want to delete any games"... Either you're talking about disk space (in which case the answer is to buy more disk space) or you need to close the games once in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not use software to solve a hardware problem.  you have to buy more ram, bigger hard-drive, faster processor, etc. readyboost does not give you more memory, it uses a USB flash device for swap files--basically this makes your machine faster because the flash device is quicker then the IDE/Sata device.